# error correction :Ankita is disgusted _____ the habit of her brother

Tags: sentence-construction

Ankita is disgusted _____ the habit of her brother.

a) at

b) with

which will be used here, and please explain other contexts too where "disgusted at" and where "disgusted with" is used. I am quite confused about it.

My book says answer is "at"

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which do you think is the answer to the question?

Comment: "I'm disgusted **at** the site of you," but "I'm disgusted **with** her habits." In your example above, it is always "with".

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it seems that ***both*** are okay! How?

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disgusted) says:

> *She was **disgusted at the way** they treated their children.*

And [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disgusted) days:

> *I'm **disgusted with the way** that he was treated.*

Comment: But does '_Ankita is disgusted with the habit of her brother_' sound natural?

Comment: If you, and I think you do, trust the dictionary, then yes! @VarunNair

Comment: Ahh, in that case, hail the mighty dictionary !!

Comment: That example above may work for both, but the original example only works with "with".

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola you mean Ankita is disgusted *with* the habit of her brother" is **incorrect?**

Comment: No, I think "Ankita is disgusted with the habit of her brother" is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Explanation – “**disgusted at**” and “**disgusted with**” have the same meaning
A little difference is that “disgusted at someone or something” means severely disappointed **at** someone or something.

Whereas “disgusted with someone or something” meaning severely disappointed **over** someone or something.